# Fancy Indexing of a 4D array (tensor)

Tags: polynomials, tensors, list-manipulation, coefficients, index

I'm trying to mimic the `CoefficientArrays` function, which I can't get to work for my symbolic equations. The `CoefficientList` function works well, and it returns a tensor that has the same information. I'm just struggling with how to extract it neatly. I'm sure I've missed something simple, but there's got to be a neat way to extract the specified columns and concatenate them into a matrix.

Here's what I want to do:

```
{rhs, lhs} = Normal[CoefficientArrays[{3 x + 4 y + 5 z + 6, 13 x + 14 y + 16}, {x, y, z}]]
{{6, 16}, {{3, 4, 5}, {13, 14, 0}}}
```

And here's my ugly mimicry, which, among other things, has to hardcode in the fact that z isn't in equation 2.

```
cl = CoefficientList[{3 x + 4 y + 5 z + 6, 
    13 x + 14 y + 16}, {x, y, z}];
rhs = cl[[1 ;; 2, 1, 1, 1]]
lhs = Transpose[{cl[[1 ;; 2, 2, 1, 1]],
                 cl[[1 ;; 2, 1, 2, 1]],
                 {cl[[1, 1, 1, 2]], 0}}]
{6, 16}
{{3, 4, 5}, {13, 14, 0}}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the discription in **Properties & Relations** section of `CoefficientList`, the following is my implementation:

```
mimicCA[poly_, var_] := 
 MapIndexed[SparseArray[#, {Length@poly, 
     Sequence @@ ConstantArray[Length@var, #2 - 1]}] &, 
  Last@Reap@MapIndexed[
     ArrayRules@SparseArray@# /. (a : {__Integer} -> b_) :> 
        Sow[#2~Join~Flatten@MapIndexed[ConstantArray[#2, #] &, a - 1] -> b, 
         Total[a - 1] + 1] &, CoefficientList[poly, var]]]
```

Not sure if this can be called neat, but it works. Test:

```
poly = {3 x + 4 y + 5 z + 6, 13 x + 14 y + 15 y^2 + 16};
var = {x, y, z};

mimicCA[poly, var] == CoefficientArrays[poly, var]
(* True *)
```

BTW, if the system is always linear, then we can simply use `D`:

```
mimicCAlinear[poly_, var_] := {poly /. Alternatives @@ var -> 0, D[poly, {var}]}

poly2 = {3 x + 4 y + 5 z + 6, 13 x + 14 y + 15 z + 16};
var2 = {x, y, z};    
mimicCAlinear[poly2, var2] == CoefficientArrays[poly2, var2]
(* True *)
```